# How to dynamically call variables defined in initializers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance

I want to dynamically call variables defined in initializers.
I have a created a file(brands.rb) in my initializers and it have some variable defined init
like,

```
FEATURED_FASHION_BRAND=["something", "something"]
FEATURED_DIY_BRAND=["something", "something"]
```

so can I call this variables dynamically, I meant, something like this,

```
@name= params[:name]
FEATURED_"#{@name}"_BRAND
```

Comment: BTW, a much nicer way to do this is to make a hash of values in your config.  Then you can just say `FEATURED_BRANDS[@name]` or similar, instead of mucking about with dynamic variable names.

Comment: And, to go further, you should actually store this stuff in your database:  it feels like it would go in a `brands` table, with a "featured" boolean field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `constantize` for that:

`"FEATURED_#{@name}_BRAND".constantize`

Comment: Note that you can use `constantize` for all sorts of things, for example to turn a string into a class:  `my_model_name.constantize.find(123)`